# L4 checksum calculation in IPv6 packets with Routing header

Tags: tcp, routes, udp, ipv6, checksum

In spec it is mentioned that in case Routing header exists TCP/UDP pseudo header is calculated as follows:

"If the IPv6 packet contains a Routing header, the Destination Address used in the pseudo-header is that of the final destination. At the originating node, that address will be in the last element of the Routing header; at the recipient(s), that address will be in the Destination Address field of the IPv6 header."

Do you understand how it works that originating node pseudo header calculation is different than recipient? wouldn't that cause the packets to be dropped at the receiving end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implementing it like this is exactly done for that reason: to make sure that the real header at the receiver's end matches the pseudo-header used in the calculation.

Imagine an IPv6 packet sent like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| IPv6 header (simplified)            |
| Source:        2001:db8::1          |
| Destination:   2001:db8:aaaa::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Routing options header (simplified) |
| Segments Left: 2                    |
| Address 1:     2001:db8:bbbb::1     |
| Address 2:     2001:db8:cccc::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Etc                                 |
```

The layer-4 checksum will be calculated with source `2001:db8::1` and destination `2001:db8:cccc::1` (the last address in the routing header).

It will arrive at `2001:db8:aaaa::1`, where the destination address and the first address in the routing header will be swapped, and the `Segments Left` counter will be decreased. Resulting in:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| IPv6 header (simplified)            |
| Source:        2001:db8::1          |
| Destination:   2001:db8:bbbb::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Routing options header (simplified) |
| Segments Left: 1                    |
| Address 1:     2001:db8:aaaa::1     |
| Address 2:     2001:db8:cccc::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Etc                                 |
```

It will arrive at `2001:db8:bbbb::1`, where the destination address and the second address in the routing header will be swapped, and the `Segments Left` counter will be decreased. Resulting in:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| IPv6 header (simplified)            |
| Source:        2001:db8::1          |
| Destination:   2001:db8:cccc::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Routing options header (simplified) |
| Segments Left: 0                    |
| Address 1:     2001:db8:aaaa::1     |
| Address 2:     2001:db8:bbbb::1     |
+-------------------------------------+
| Etc                                 |
```

This will arrive at `2001:db8:cccc::1` who will see that there are no more segments left and that it is therefore the final recipient. It will use the source and destination addresses from the main IPv6 header in the checksum calculations, which are the same addresses that the sender used. The checksum will therefore match.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! so this means that in the example for 2001:db8:bbbb::1 & 2001:db8:aaaa::1 won't have matching L4 checksum, right? so are they expected to know that since the packet has a routing header and they're not the final destination so they shouldn't process L4 data?

Comment: If they're not the final destination they don't have any business looking at the layer 4 stuff. And if they do they'll have to understand the routing header impact on checksum calculation.